# Tracking Url & Number for individual order item

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

I am facing some issues in Shipping email. Now I want to show the  shipping details like Tracking Url, Tracking number to be shown against each order line in shipping email. In theory each line could be shipped via a different carrier. How Can I achieve this in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible in Magento. You should create a shipment for each order line individually. Then each shipment can have its own tracking code, which you can send to the customer.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

if($order->canShip()) {
    $itemQty =  $order->getItemsCollection()->count();
    $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment($itemQty);
    $shipment = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api();
    $shipmentId = $shipment->create($orderId);
}
```

Do this for every order line, for the ones you don't want to send, set the `$itemQty` to 0, so it won't be added to the shipment.

The `$itemQty` is an array containing the desired quantity to ship for each order item:

```
array(
  'order_item_id'=>$qty,
  'order_item_id'=>$qty,
  'order_item_id'=>$qty
)
```

Comment: Do you have any code to create a shipment for each order line individually.

Comment: @ArjunManoharan See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi Its creating shipment for each and every product. Without creating multiple shipment I need to achieve this. Is there any way.

Comment: I get that. Please understand that `$itemQty)` is an array containing the desired amounts for each order line. I updated my answer.